# Sensenet: sort by file type on List View

Tags: sensenet

It is possible to sort the content on a list view by file type?
For instance I want to see all the doc files first, then the folders, then the pdf files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Sense/Net to sort by a value, you have to have a dedicated field for that value, because our search engine can sort only by fields.
Unfortunately the value of file extension is not stored in a dedicated field like that, however it is possible to display it. You need to add a new "extension" field to the CTD of the files:

```
<Field name="Extension" type="ShortText">
  <DisplayName>Extension of the file.</DisplayName>
</Field>
```

and define a ContentHandeler, inherited from File, that has access to the file name, and can retrive the extension. For further details visit SenseNet-wiki: http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_a_ContentHandler